# $AA^{*}-I$ is negative semi-definite

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I need to show $(AA^{*}-I)$ is negative semi-definite where A is a linear operator.

I can show $AA^{*}+I$ is positive definite since $\langle x, (AA^{*}+I)x  \rangle=\|A^{*}x\|^2+\|x\|^2>0$ for $x \neq 0$  but I am not sure how to show $\langle x, (AA^{*}-I)x  \rangle \leq 0$.

Any ideas?

p.s. I think it was assumed that $\|AA^{*}-I\| <1$ if that helps.

Comment: Is it possible the assumption was actually $\|AA^*\| < 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $AA^{*}-I$ is not negative semi-definite:

Let $A$ be the $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix $A= diag(2,2).$ Then

$$AA^*-I= diag (3,3),$$

wich is positive definite !

Comment: ok, I think I'm missing some extra assumptions. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\sqrt{1.5} I$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Then $AA^*-I$ isn't negative semi-definite although $\|AA^*-I\|<1$.